# How to combine wget and grep

Tags: grep, wget

I have a html-page url and I want to grep it. How can I do it by `wget someArgs | grep keyword`?

My first idea was `wget -q -O - url | grep keyword`, but wget's output bypass grep and arise on the terminal in its original form.

Comment: grep selects lines delimited by (e.g.) carriage return and linefeed characters, an HTML response doesn't have lines it has text with markup like <br> or <p> so the whole web-page could look like one line to grep

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The OP's command works flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way is to  use `curl` with the option `-s` for *silent:*

```
curl -s http://somepage.com | grep whatever
```

Comment: @slhck: Both commands do exactly the same for me.

Comment: @Dennis Try `curl`ing `http://superuser.com/questions/431581`. For whatever reason I tested it with this particular URL and got no output. Dunno what I'm missing.

Comment: @slhck: Curl doesn't follow redirects by default. It does with the `-L` switch.

Comment: @Dennis Didn't know what you were talking about without seeing the deleted comments – but yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Question asks for wget. Not curl. This won't work with multiple redirects and -L option.

Answer (score 15):

Keeping this around for the sake of completeness.

Your example should actually work. The syntax is correct, and [here's a screencast I just took demonstrating it](http://screencast.com/t/x9P7OJ3P0Qi), with a good old GNU `wget` 1.13.4.

> `wget -q some-url -O - | grep something`

So assume your pattern is wrong and `grep` will just output everything it got.

Comment: It could also be a typo in the URL. With `-q`, there is no error message.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to grep or pipe headers, they are standard directed to stderr so you need to redirect them. Eg:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/page.php > /dev/null 2>&1 | grep HTTP
```

Comment: See also the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302195/parse-http-response-header-from-wget)

Answer (score 3):

[This bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/getgnuwin32/bugs/28/) was in v1.12.1  fixed in [another version](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions?action=show&redirect=Faq#download). Currently I use v1.15 and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `wget` writes its output to `stderr`   not to `stdout`, so one needs to redirect the `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
wget -q -O - url 2&>1 | grep keyword
```