# Why is this grep skipped after wget?

Tags: bash, grep, wget

I'm trying to grep a string from the HTML output from wget in order to concatenate a URL together. Using the suggestions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/431581/how-to-combine-wget-and-grep) I tried

```
wget -O - https://www.printable-puzzles.com/download.php?p=cw2&f=h4aHZGdsa4djoZmY | grep -Eio '\/dl\.php\?.+\.pdf'
```

but the entire HTML is displayed in the terminal as if the pipe and grep command weren't there. I've already checked the regex pattern by saving the HTML in a file and running grep on that, so the pattern isn't the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL contains an `&` character, which acts as a command separator in shell (and causes the preceding command to run in background). So you're actually running two separate commands:

1. `wget -O - https://www.printable-puzzles.com/download.php?p=cw2` (background job)
2. `f=h4aHZGdsa4djoZmY | grep -Eio '\/dl\.php\?.+\.pdf'` (normal)

Use quotes around the URL to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement looks fine and should be returning what you expect. I can't try your exact example as the URI isn't available (anymore?). But just to make sure to get as clean of an output as possible, you might want to make sure to leave stderr output out:

```sh
wget -O - https://www.printable-puzzles.com/download.php?p=cw2&f=h4aHZGdsa4djoZmY 2>/dev/null | grep -Eio '\/dl\.php\?.+\.pdf'
```

(Note the `2>/dev/null`.)